# How to group by multiple columns and with only date part of datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I a have dataframe like this

| CELL ID | Party | LOC | Date & Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10631 | 3009787 | bwp | 2021-10-01 8:20:30 |
| 10631 | 3009787 | bwp | 2021-10-01 8:40:50 |
| 50987 | 2275172 | bwp | 2021-10-02 7:50:20 |
| 50987 | 2275172 | bwp | 2021-10-02 7:23:16 |

I want output dataframe which contains grouped data .Use CELL ID, Party & Only Date Part of Date  & time in group :

Output in this Format : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFaDS.png

CELL ID -->Party --> Date & Time

Comment: Your `Date & Time` column currently only contains a date. What's the problem? Can you please provide a more representative sample dataframe?

Comment: groups should only contain date part of date & Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
# df["Date & Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date & Time"])  # If not already datetime
df.set_index(["CELL ID", "Party", df["Date & Time"].dt.date])
```

Output:

```py
                             LOC         Date & Time
CELL ID Party   Date & Time
10631   3009787 2021-10-01   bwp 2021-10-01 08:20:30
                2021-10-01   bwp 2021-10-01 08:40:50
50987   2275172 2021-10-02   bwp 2021-10-02 07:50:20
                2021-10-02   bwp 2021-10-02 07:23:16
```

Comment: Now how can we combines these groups into a single dataframe

Comment: Wait, if that's what you want to do, then why not just remove the time values altogether, and the drop duplicates?

Comment: I want a dataframe that contains all these groups

Comment: You're going to need to provide your desired outcome because it's no longer clear what you're asking for.

Comment: @ZulqarnainSabir see my edit

Comment: @ZulqarnainSabir were you helped by my answer?